# Difference between Entity and Value Objects in translation app

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity, value-objects

I am modelling domain for typical translation application to translate word between different  world languages:

[image]

That is my first DDD experience, however, I have quite OOP practice and therefore I've been surprised with confusing between Entity and Value Object concepts.

I am sure that `Language` and `Word` objects have to be defined as Entity, but I am doubting regard `Translation`. Currently, it is defined as Value Object. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The important point to distinguish them is that identity matters for entities, but does not matter for value objects. As can be seen in your class diagram, there isn't any identity for `Translation` so it's value object.